# Show table data using by filter from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a data table which is getting complete date as I have from the spreadsheet.

```
<script>

function createTable(dataArray) {

    if(dataArray){
    
      var result = "<table class='table table-sm' style='font-size:0.8em'>"+

                   "<thead style='white-space: nowrap'>"+

                     "<tr>"+        //Change table headings to match with he Google Sheet
                      "<th scope='col'>Delete</th>"+

                      "<th scope='col'>Edit</th>"+

                      "<th scope='col'>ID</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>Type</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>serial</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>ssbarcode</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>market</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>program</th>"+

                      "<th scope='col'>owner</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>condition</th>"+
                      "<th scope='col'>active</th>"+
                      
                    "</tr>"+
                  "</thead>";
      for(var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++) {
          result += "<tr>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteBtn' onclick='deleteData(this);'>Delete</button></td>";
          result += "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs editBtn' onclick='editData(this);'>Edit</button></td>";
          for(var j=0; j<dataArray[i].length; j++){
              result += "<td>"+dataArray[i][j]+"</td>";
          }
          result += "</tr>";
      }
      result += "</table>";
      var div = document.getElementById('inventorydataTable');
      div.innerHTML = result;
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
    }else{
      var div = document.getElementById('inventorydataTable');
      div.innerHTML = "Data not found!";
    }
  }
</script>
```

/* requirement */

Now I wanted to get the data from "inventorydataTable" using filters on UI like if I select only for "US" than table should show for the "US" market data.

Comment: Show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: So what's keeping you from being able to accomplish your goal?

Answer (score 0):

### Sample how to filter rows HTML side

You need to create a filter functionality consisting of two steps:

1.Create an input field where the user inserts a string to filter for (e.g. US) and bind an [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event listener to it.

Sample:

```
 <input type="text"  id="myFilter" onkeyup="filterRows()">';
```

2. Write funciton `filterRows()` to apply the filter to the column of your choice (the one where you expect to find `US`)

Sample:

```js
         function filterRows(a) {
             var table = document.getElementById("ID OF YOUR TABLE");
             var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
             var length = tr.length;
             // specify the column on which you want to perform the filtering:
             var columnNumber = 2;
             var searchField = document.getElementById("myFilter");
             var filter = searchField.value;
             // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
             for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
                 var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("t")[columnNumber];
                 var  input = td.innerHTML;
                 if (input && input.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                     tr[i].style.display = "";
                 } else {
                     tr[i].style.display = "none";
                 }
             }
         }
```

**References:**

- [eventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)
- [getElementsByTagName](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)
- [Style display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp)

Comment: passing error 

"TypeError: tr.getElementsByTagName is not a function
    at filterRows (userCodeAppPanel:13)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup (userCodeAppPanel:1) "

Comment: The code snippets above are not an alone-standing funcitonality, but samples to be adapted and integrated into your existing code! Make sure you give an `id` to your table, execute function `filterRows()` after building the table and use a `columnNumber` that actually exists in yourr table (be careful: the first array element is `0`!).